# Why is mvn clean install -U not working: Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: maven

I have cloned [the repository](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-addins) from github and issues `mvn clean install -U` but for some reason I am getting:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-addins:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-parent:pom:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-addins:[unknown-version] (E:\java\gwt-material\gwt-material-addins\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-addins:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-parent:pom:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

How can I solve this error? I actually want to update my local repository since there was an update that I depend on. I can't remember how I installed the dependency in the first place but back then I didn't get this error. Is the error even on my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a great design there. You are getting this error because [gwt-material-addins](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-addins) depends on a SNAPSHOT version of `gwt-material-parent` but that artifact is not deployed in any repository (in SNAPSHOT version).

As such, you need to clone and install [gwt-material](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material) first. This will install `gwt-material-parent` in the correct SNAPSHOT version and then, you will be able to build `gwt-material-addins`.

To recap:

- Clone `https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material`
- Run `mvn clean install` on `gwt-material`
- Then run `mvn clean install` on `gwt-material-addins`.